# Spring Boot 3.2.1 GitHub OAuth2 check which Orgs/Teams someone is in

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, github-oauth

I have been trying hard to get some kind of GitHub OAuth2 Login for my Spring Boot project to work. While I got it running on the Default, I want to check which Orgs and Teams someone is in, to determine if they can use certain resources. I checked YouTube, Baeldungs Website, and other guides, but either they are just implementing some general OAuth2 or just GitHub without any real explanations.
The only option I can think of doesn't use Spring Boot in any way and that would be to query the user via GitHubs API. It could also be that I am just mixing stuff up here, I am not that proficient in authentication.

Does anyone have some resource or tip that can point me in the right direction?

As explained I tried different methods from old guides, but never really succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "Github OAuth2" and "general OAuth2"?

OAuth2 is just a standard protocol for authorization. You can achieve OAuth2 implementation using [Spring Security OAuth2 framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html) which supports authorization servers, resource servers and clients. If you want more fine-grained authorization, there is Spring ACL to help you with that.

Comment: I am using OAuth2 to limit access, and for that, I am currently using GitHub as a provider. Currently, I can log in via GitHub and get stuff like the user's name, etc, but I want more information to verify the user.

Comment: the resource you provided has seemingly done it for me, the chapter talking about [accessing protected resourced](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html#oauth2-client-access-protected-resources) was helpful. I will take that to access the API from GitHub and query it as needed